# Passing sqlContext when testing a method

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following test case:

```
  test("check foo") {
    val conf = new SparkConf()
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlc = new SQLContext(sc)

    val res = foo("A", "B")
    assert(true)
  }
```

Which checks the following method:

```
  def foo(arg1: String, arg2: String) (implicit sqlContext: SQLContext) : Seq[String] = {
    //some other code
  }
```

When running the tests I get the following issue:

```
Error:(65, 42) could not find implicit value for parameter sqlContext: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
val res = foo("A", "B")
```

How can I share the `SqlContext` instance I create in the test method with `foo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `implicit` in front of `val sqlc`:

```
implicit val sqlc = new SQLContext(sc)
```